# iOS Reachability not working

Tags: ios, reachability

I'm using the popular Reachability framework (https://github.com/tonymillion/Reachability) in my app and I'm testing reachability on a **real device** (though it's exactly the same behavior on simulator too).

Here is my code (I'm strongly referencing the `Reachability` instance as an instance variable in my app delegate):

```
@implementation AppDelegate{
    Reachability *reachability;
}


- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    [...]

    //this code is reached and called with no issues.

    reachability = [Reachability reachabilityWithAddress:@"myreachabledomain.com"];
    [reachability startNotifier];
    return YES;
}
```

In somewhere else (again, strongly referenced):

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
              selector:@selector(reachabilityDidChange:)
              name:kReachabilityChangedNotification object:nil];

[...]

-(void)reachabilityDidChange:(NSNotification*)note{
    NSLog(@"hello");
}
```

However, I never get to see that "hello" (or hit the breakpoint). My domain is perfectly accessible. I toggle my phone's internet connectivity by permanently setting cellular data off, then running my app and toggling WiFi (yep, it connects to WiFi without issues and I can browse the internet).

What am I doing wrong? (I'm on iPhone 7 Plus, iOS 10.3.1)

**UPDATE:**

- I've tried `google.com` instead of my custom domain, no avail.
- I've tried registering for notification before starting listening, no avail.
- I've tried using the block-based methods instead of notification center, no avail.

Comment: Add the observer before calling `startNotifier`. Btw: I'd prefer the block based API.

Comment: @vadian tried both (registering before starting, and block-based API). neither seem to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm a bit late to the party but I just tried and was having the same issue.

I tried using `[Reachability reachabilityWithHostName:@"google.com"];` instead of `reachabilityWithAddress` and it works as expected.

I can't explain why this works right now but hopefully you can use this option.